# Variation of the (x) button - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

You know the (x) button on the toolbar of your app? I want to add a piece of code right after the it closes the window. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a handler to the [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28VS.80%29.aspx) event. Looking at the [CloseReason property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason%28VS.80%29.aspx) of the received [FormClosingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs%28VS.80%29.aspx) you will know if the form is closing because the user explicitly closed the window or for any other reason.

**EDIT**: FormClosing will fire *before* the window is actually closed, and you can cancel this event so that the window is not actually closed. FormClosed, mentioned by Jon, will fire *after* the window is closed.

Answer (score 4):

Attach an event handler to the [`Form.FormClosed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) event.